# How to send mail from a specific account?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using Office 365 (Outlook Version 1909 Build 12026.20264).

I configured two email accounts (a@a.com and b@b.com) and one shared mailbox (shared@b.com).

With my b@b.com account I have permission to send email from shared@b.com.

I can manually send email from all accounts (a@a.com, b@b.com, shared@b.com).

I have VBA code to send email from shared@b.com using the SentOnBehalfOfName property.

```vb
Sub TEST()
  Dim origEmail As MailItem
  Dim replyEmail As MailItem

  Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
  Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\...\Template.oft")

  replyEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "shared@b.com"
  replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
  replyEmail.Subject = "RE:" + origEmail.Subject

  replyEmail.Display
End Sub
```

Usually this sends emails correctly. I can see they go to the sent folder in the b@b.com account.

Sometimes it tries to send emails using the a@a.com account (which has no permission to send emails from shared@b.com). I receive an error email in a@a.com and the email is not sent.

How can I change my code so that everytime I am sending email from shared@b.com it will use my b@b.com account?

Note: I set my b@b.com account as my default account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `SendUsingAccount` property to the `Account` object corresponding to the b@b.com mailbox.

```
Sub TEST()
  Dim origEmail As MailItem
  Dim replyEmail As MailItem

  Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
  Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\...\Template.oft")

  for each acc in Application.Session.Accounts
    if acc.DisplayName = "b@b.com" Then 
      replyEmail.SendUsingAccount = acc
      Exit for
    End If
  next 

  replyEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "shared@b.com"
  replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
  replyEmail.Subject = "RE:" + origEmail.Subject

  replyEmail.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: How? Can you explain it please.

Comment: I mean should I use SentOnBehalfOfName and SendUsingAccount? Please can you help me with this making the require changes in my code?

Comment: If you have multiple Exchange accounts, then yes, you might need o also set SendUsingAccount